# How can I return a CLLocation value in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation

I am trying to create function which can return CLLocation value?

As this is asynch method it gives value after some time and return get called before that. is there any way to return after getting lat, lon?

```
func setLocation(location: String) -> [String]{
            var lat: CLLocationDegrees?
            var lon: CLLocationDegrees?
            geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location) { placemarks, error in
                let placemark = placemarks?.first
                lat = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude
                lon = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude
                print("Lat: \(lat), Lon: \(lon)") //here i get value
            }

            print("Lat: \(lat), Lon: \(lon)") //but here i get nil

            return ["\(String(describing: lat))", "\(String(describing: lon))"]

        }
```

Comment: instead of return use completion handler

Comment: Thanks @jawadAli i am might not sure how to do this if possible can you provide code snippet please?

Comment: @Sh_khann provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a completion

```
func setLocation(location: String,completion:@escaping(CLLocationCoordinate2D? -> ())) {
            var lat: CLLocationDegrees?
            var lon: CLLocationDegrees?
            geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location) { placemarks, error in
                let placemark = placemarks?.first
                completion(placemark?.location?.coordinate) 
            }
}
```

---

```
setLocation(location: "") { (coor) in
   print(coor.latitude)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. as i am new to this may i know how can i use it?

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Comment: see edit............................